# Two version XCode coexist issue, now none of them can't be launched

Tags: xcode

Install two version Xcode, 4.2 in /Developer and 4.0.1 in /Developer2, located in different directory on theory both of them should work well, no disturb between the two, but the fact is that now neither of them can launch successfully.

My questions:

1, Is it possible to let them coexist? If yes, possible error for my installation?
2. How can I find more clues why launch failed?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly Xcode gives you some hints by logging error messages. Launch Xcode from the terminal or open the Console application to see what gets logged.

Comment: See the following error message when running in terminal, still doesn't know how to fix it, any more suggestion? 


dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
  Referenced from: /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap

Comment: Please edit your original answer instead of writing an unreadable comment. Ow and there's a file missing. So the installation of Xcode probably failed, or you accidentally removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bandejapaisa is correct, I have 3 on my machine; you can un-install these xcode (remember to restart after each un-installation) and install one by one; it should work